# How to align buttons in a row of Bootstrap thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this jQuery code to align a row of Bootstrap thumbnails:

```
<script>
function equalHeight(group) {    
    var tallest = 0;    
    group.each(function() {       
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();       
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {          
            tallest = thisHeight;       
        }    
    });    
    group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });
} 

$(document).ready(function() {   
    equalHeight($(".thumbnail")); 
});
</script>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Question:

How can I also align the 4 buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using flex. Wrap all your content, except the button in a div. Then apply `flex-direction:column;justify-content:space-between;` on the parent div.

Here's an example.I am setting `.col` to a fixed width, since you are doing an equivalent thing using jquery.

```css
.col{
  width:150px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:230px;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <h3>Family</h3>
     <p>This is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a text
  This is a textThis is a textThis is a text</p>
  </div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <h3>Women</h3>
    <p>This is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a text</p>
  </div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```